# Next.js middleware not functioning correctly in TypeScript - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

My problem is that following documentation, Next.js's middleware are not working as I ewxpected.

I tried this. The simpletst middleware I can imagine.

I expected navigating throw /, ... a console message will appear. But nothing happened.

Here the code:

[image: image representation of the code]

I've also removed package-lock. Reinstalled everything. Now this is my package file:

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/swc-darwin-x64": "13.4.4",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.0",
    "next": "13.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next list"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.15.11",
    "@types/react": "18.0.35"
  }
}
```

Comment: where have you placed this file?

Comment: app/middleware.ts (I've also update the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NextJS 13+ requires `middleware` file to be at the root level of your source instead of `app/` or any other folder.

So your **middleware file** and project dir should look like

```
├── next.config.ts
├── middleware.ts
├── .env, package.json, or any other project files
├── app
├── pages
├── public
├── src
```

[Reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am translating all the documentation in videos for youtube. I am reading a lot, ... but sometimes I am missing some piece like this. Thank you very very much. Home this question may help someone other.